# Exporting two display tags from same page

Tags: java, displaytag

I have tried to export two display tags from same page independently.but first display tag is exported even for export option in second displaytag

Comment: post your jsp/display tag code here

Comment: Here's how you solve this problem...

Comment: @zEro follow this link http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/

Answer (score 0):

Check the link [displaytag1.2](http://demo.displaytag.org/displaytag-examples-1.2/example-twotables.jsp) here. It has the examples. Click on View Source for the respective code.